# Cannot mount storage volume

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, storage

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.3. I connected a storage unit (IBM Storwize v3700). I cannot getting it to be mounted to the server. I followed the following steps.

- install multipath

sudo multipath -ll

> 36005076300808b9e4800000000000003 dm-2 IBM     ,2145
>       size=500G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
>          |-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=50 status=active
>          | `- 1:0:0:0 sdb 8:16 active ready running`
>   -+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=10 status=enabled
>            `- 1:0:1:0 sdc 8:32 active ready running

- create a partition table on /dev/sdb

sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt

- format a partition
  sudo parted /dev/sdb mkpart primary ext4 1G 500G
- mount it on the folder /storwize I created
  sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /storwize

This is where I have the error

> mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /storwize busy

I might be mistaken on what to mount, considering that fdisk -l gives me for my storage /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc (no partition table), and /dev/mapper/36005076300808b9e4800000000000003 (no partition table) (all with the size of my storage).

Here is the full output of

> sudo fdisk -l
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 299.0 GB, 298999349248 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36351 cylinders, total 583983104 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00042ec1
>
> ```
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
> ```
>
> /dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2          501758   583981055   291739649    5  Extended
>   /dev/sda5          501760   583981055   291739648   8e  Linux LVM
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders, total 1048576000 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
>
> Disk /dev/sdc: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders, total 1048576000 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--leno1--vg-root: 230.2 GB, 230242123776 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 27992 cylinders, total 449691648 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--leno1--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--leno1--vg-swap_1: 68.5 GB, 68451041280 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 8322 cylinders, total 133693440 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--leno1--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/36005076300808b9e4800000000000003: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders, total 1048576000 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00000000
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/36005076300808b9e4800000000000003 doesn't contain a valid partition table

And of

> mount
>
> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--leno1--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
>   none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
>   none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
>   none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
>   udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
>   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
>   tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
>   none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
>   none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
>   none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
>   none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
>   /dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
>   systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)

Comment: I'm representing IBM Storage Support. In order to provide you the appropriate support, you need to open a PMR, so we can now the details of your Storage enviroment. You can check toll-free number for your country on this link: http://www.ibm.com/planetwide/index.html#region